# Creating Backwards Compatible Drop In Statically Linked DLL

Tags: c, visual-studio, dll

I have a C-based DLL that I wrote years ago for a project and it exports a set of functions that define an API. Now I need to re-write this DLL's internals but keep the API exactly the same.

The user of the DLL used static linking and they do not want to or are unable to recompile their executable.

I've noticed that the RVAs of the exported functions are different. My understanding is that means the executable won't be able to find the functions unless it is re-linked with the updated lib file.

Is there a way in VS2017 to force an exported function to use a specific RVA? I checked the Microsoft LINK DEF file format and I didn't see an option in there.

Even if it is possible, is fixing the RVAs enough to ensure the old executable will be able to use the updated DLL or are there additional complications that make this a non-starter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user has statically linked in your library, then it is not a DLL, and making a drop in replacement without relinking is not possible. At least not without some ugly hacks. The old library functions have been copied into the executable, so there are no way around editing the executable. If you can't recompile or relink, then it is probably easier to rewrite the executable from scratch.

Mucking around with adresses of functions in your new DLL, if possible, can't have any effect if the executable doesn't have any code to load a DLL at all.

Answer (score 1):

When you statically link an EXE module against a DLL, you do indeed link against the the DLL's import library (a .LIB) created alongside the DLL when the DLL was built.  This is *not* the same thing as linking against a static library which is confusing because those are also .LIB files.

The first thing you should do is figure out if your EXE module has an import entry for said DLL using a tool like [Dependency Walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/), [Dumpbin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-options?view=vs-2019), [pelook](http://bytepointer.com/tools/index.htm#pelook) or your favorite PE analyzer tool.  If there is no DLL import entry, you have have probably linked the EXE against a static library as described by @HAL9000 's answer.  Short of reverse-engineering the EXE, your best bet would be to rebuild the module as suggested if possible.

Otherwise, if you do find an import for said DLL, then yes you *can* swap out a newly-built DLL provided you have the same export (function) names and/or ordinal values as the original.  DLLs find function by export names and/or ordinal values, not RVAs which in this case are only an internal detail.  Whether the DLL is implicitly loaded (from being statically-linked) during process (EXE) initialization (before the EXE's entry point is called) or explicitly loaded (via code using LoadLibrary, etc.) the whole point of being a DLL is that it is a module is designed to be *dynamically* replaced and Windows was designed around this concept.  The internal RVAs both within the EXE (referencing the DLL) and the DLL itself do not need to match an old DLL's values; this bookkeeping is automatically handled by the Windows loader during a process also known as runtime linking.

In the event the EXE is linked against said DLL and *ALSO* specifies hard-coded addresses (RVAs) for the DLL's exported functions (a process known as static binding), Windows will still verify the addresses still internally reflect the correct values in the DLL that is actually loaded which may be a different, updated DLL. This is done via a timestamp check in the import section for the DLL.  If there is a mismatch, the Windows loader tosses-out all of the static RVAs and updates them with the current values incurring a slight performance penalty, but the program will still load.  FWIW the bind.exe tool to do this static binding no longer ships with the Visual C++ toolset as the performance gain in modern versions of Windows is minimal. This optimization used to be be common practice to speed up load times, especially in OS-supplied system DLLs, but shouldn't affect what you are trying to do one way or the other.